# ((Code::Blocks)) - fatal error: stdafx.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks version 16.01, and I am learning from www.learncpp.com, on lesson 1.3a. My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number: "; // ask user for a number
    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x; // read number from console and store it in x
    std::cout << "You entered " << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The entire program works fine, but there's only one error and that's the #include stdafx.h; I'm getting the error listed in the title. Help and a somewhat clear explanation would be nice for me (I'm clearly inexperienced).

Comment: What happens when you remove the line?

Comment: Just remove `#include "stdafx.h"`.

Comment: Don't use `stdafx.h` unless you have a lot of include files that don't change.  For most smaller projects, precompiled headers don't save build time.  If one header file is changed, then the precompiled header has to be compiled again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

stdafx.h is used by Visual Studio's implementation of precompiled headers. If you aren't using VS either

Copy the stdafx.h file from your Visual Studio project folder into the Code::Blocks project folder and carry on with the build.

or

If you don't have a Visual Studio project, delete the `#include "stdafx.h"` liine. Odds are pretty good that if you don't have stdafx.h there is nothing in it that you need. The compiler well let you know pretty quickly if the odds weren't in your favour.

Answer (score 3):

You delete `#include "stdafx.h"`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

We use in visual studio :).

Comment: Not always. You can have a project without precompiled headers, then you'll get the same error :)

Comment: Nice dyziok122. +1